# Boundfield not returning count from LINQ query

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I have a grouped LINQ query with a count summary line that I am binding to a gridview but the count field in the gridview just shows 'System.Data.DataRow[]'

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

aspx:

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Service_Name" HeaderText="Impacted services"/>
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Fieldname" HeaderText="Count"/>
```

vb code:

```
 Dim Services = From Lines In dtMain _
 Where Lines.Field(Of String)("ULTIMATE_PARENT_NAME") = lstUPs.SelectedItem.ToString _
 Group By Parent_Name = Lines.Field(Of String)("ULTIMATE_PARENT_NAME"), _
 Service_Name = Lines.Field(Of String)("THIRD_PARTY_SERVICE_CLEAN") _
 Into Fieldname = Group, Count()
 grdOuterGridView.DataSource = Services
 grdOuterGridView.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert on that syntax (I use the extension methods) but it looks to me like `Fieldname` is being assigned the value `Group`, or the collection of rows that are being grouped on `Parent_Name` and `Service_Name`.  Perhaps you need to define a field name for the result of `Count()`?

ETA:  Got it.  You should say `Group.Count()`, not `Group, Count()`.

Comment: How about `Group.Count` without the parentheses?